# special characters in url filename cause problems

Tags: php, apache2

I have the following www.mywebsite.com/upload/server/php/files/foto/test/Aston_Martin_DBS_V12_coupé_(rear)_b-w.jpg

This file is uploaded trough a script. The file exists on the server.
However, because the special character in the url (é), I am experiencing some problems.

The filename on the server is `Aston_Martin_DBS_V12_coup%C3%A9_(rear)_b-w.jpg`, which is correct. However somehow my browser (Chrome) requests this page as ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8.

Therefore, I get a 404.
[image]

I am using jQuery file upload plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my answer from here and i wrote new:

Usually websites does not contain files with non-standard characters. Files usually have removed non standard characters, sometimes that characters are replaced by similar standard chars (Polish ą to a, ś to s). For example - im renaming files manually, or when i have a lot of files - i just use bash or php script that removes/replaces that characters in filenames on server.

Anyway, if you HAVE TO use original filenames - you have to decode them from ISO and encode them to UTF8.

Take look at that php code fragment here:

[how to serve HTTP files with special characters](https://serverfault.com/questions/153826/how-to-serve-http-filenames-with-special-characters)

Comment: You mean, changing the filename during/right after uploading?

Comment: Changing to urlencode produces this: `Aston_Martin_DBS_V12_coup%25C3%25E9_(rear)_b-w.jpg` which also doesn't work

Comment: That's what urlencode makes of it.. remember: the original filename before upload is also `Aston_Martin_DBS_V12_coup%C3%A9_(rear)_b-w.jpg`

Comment: I messed up. This is not that kind of problem. Check EDIT in my answer.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to keep the original filenames, but changing them (i.e. applying utf8_encode or urlencode) does not solve the problem.

Comment: So remove that characters from filenames or make some translation function and rename files by bash script/php script/code in upload function.

Answer (score 0):

Some special Charater make problem in url for filename 
like

```
+ ,#,%,&
```

For those file which are accessing through url make file which not contain above letters
forex

```
str_replace(array(" ","&","'","+","#","%"),"-","filename")
```

it will works fine

Answer (score -1):

If the *filename* contains the `%` character codes, you will need to encode those in your URL. Try accessing `Aston_Martin_DBS_V12_coup%25C3%25E9_(rear)_b-w.jpg`